# Wrap with a function to return a different type

Tags: c++, wrapper

I have a struct `x` which needs to be converted to something else before it is given to a function as an argument.

For example,

```
static struct ss x = {{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, {x3, y3, z3}};

int out1 = function1( std::span<const a>(x))
int out2 = function2( std::span<const a>(x))
int out3 = function3( std::span<const a>(x))
```

Insted of converting inside the function call as `std::span<const a>(x)`, how do I wrap x inside a function to return in the type `std::span<const a>?`

So that I can call the functions as `int out1 = function1( funx())`

Else, what is the most simple way to call `functionx` with `x` as the argument of type std::span

Comment: Please don't post identical questions multiple times. There also appears to be no additional info from your original question. And you're still missing the [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want: `span funx () { return span (x); }`.